# Should I use props or state to store TreeView data?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and I'm trying to create a TreeView component.
This TreeView can receive the data itself (through 'data' prop) or as an url to a rest resource. I'm focusing on this last option here.

The component is first rendered in a 'loading' state and the ajax call is made on componentDidMount.
When data is return from the REST service I just assign it to component's 'props.data' and setState({loading:false}) and it correctly renders the filled up tree.

One problem here is that I'm mutating props from the component itself witch is an anti-pattern in react but also it doesn't feels right to add data to state.
I tend to see state as related to UI interaction and use it to things like "collapsed" or "selected"
When updating the parent component (the one containing the TreeView) the treeView 'data' prop is reseted (componentDidMount is not called so it's not even fetched again) and component breaks.
Using 'state' fixes this as it's value is maintained during this parent re-render.

Should state be used here? Is there any better pattern for this?

Besides retrieving data from server there's also the problem of changing the tree data itself (like moving an tree item no another place)
Right now I just change the items in 'props.data' and forceUpdate the relevant inner components.

Should I just use state and setState in the TreeView root component and let react diff the whole thing again? It's quite a large tree by the way...
Should I wrap the tree in some other data component that will pass down the 'data'?

Can someone help find the best way to structure this component?
Thanks and Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call your Rest service in the `componentDidMount` method of the parent component (the one containing the `TreeView`) and set the tree data to the parent components state. This way you wont be mutating props of the component yourself and parent component updates will not reset `Treeview's` data. (A better practice would be using [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content) stores to store and fetch data and pass that data to your `TreeView` through controller-views.)

As for changing the tree data itself, you can define callback functions in parent component and call these functions from the `TreeView` when data changes. Actual data assignments occur in the callback function in the parent component. This causes the parent component rerender which rerenders the `TreeView`. (Also a better practice would be calling Flux actions in the parent component to change the data kept in the stores which is then propagated to the views.)